# Unable to upload the xlsx file using Apex and Visualforce, why?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am not able to upload the xlsx file using the below code. why ? Do I need to make any modifications? Please suggest.

```
An error has occured while importin data Please make sure input csv file is correct.
```

**ImportDataFromCSVController**

```
public class ImportDataFromCSVController {
    private static final String errorMesg = 'An error has occured while importin data Please make sure input csv file is correct';

    public Blob csvFileBody {get; set;}
    public string csvAsString {get;set;}
    public String[] csvFileLines {get;set;}
    public List<account> acclist {get;set;}

    public ImportDataFromCSVController(){
        csvFileLines = new String[]{};
        acclist = New List<Account>(); 
    }

    public void importCSVFile(){
        try{
            csvAsString = csvFileBody.toString();
            csvFileLines = csvAsString.split('\n'); 

            for(Integer i=1; i < csvFileLines.size(); i++){
                    Account acct = new Account();
                    string[] csvRecordData = csvFileLines[i].split(',');
                    acct.name = csvRecordData[0] ;             
                    acct.accountnumber = csvRecordData[1];
                    acct.Type = csvRecordData[2];
                    acct.AccountSource = csvRecordData[3];   
                    acct.Industry = csvRecordData[4];                                                                             
                    acclist.add(acct); 
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                ApexPages.Message errorMessage = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,errorMesg);
                ApexPages.addMessage(errorMessage);
            } 
        }
    }
```

and **ImportDataFromCSVControllerVFPage**

```
<apex:page controller="ImportDataFromCSVController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:messages />
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:inputFile value="{!csvFileBody}" fileName="{!csvAsString}" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Import Account" action="{!importCSVFile}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!acclist}" var="acc">
                <apex:column value="{!acc.Name}" />
                <apex:column value="{!acc.AccountNumber}" />
                <apex:column value="{!acc.Type}" />
                <apex:column value="{!acc.Accountsource}" />
                <apex:column value="{!acc.Industry}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Comment: You can not upload an XLS file when your code is expecting a CSV format.

Comment: Open the xlsx file, hit save as, and choose `.csv`.

Comment: What changes in code do I need to make in order to accepts the xlsx or xls format ?

Comment: @user4567570 Since it looks like you're trying to extract values from your uploaded file, the changes you'd need to make would require an enormous amount of work. You'd need to build something (specifically, a parser) that understands the xls and xlsx file formats which, I can assure you, is no simple task. The amount of time you would sink into this wouldn't be worth the end result. CSV files really are the way to go here.

Comment: If you're dead-set on accepting xlsx files, the [Office Open XML File Formats](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm) page contains over 6000 pages of information, and [Microsoft's extensions to the Office Open XML File Formats](http://interoperability.blob.core.windows.net/files/MS-XLSX/[MS-XLSX].pdf) is another 297 pages on top of that.